Сhange the first image of a video, thumbnail, fia FFmpeg
Need to change thumbnail. This is a picture that is displayed for a video file, as a preview.
Need to assign to another one from the same video file, knowing the time of this picture.
Some command:
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 changeThumbnailToThis(time=01:20) -c copy "newVideo.mp4" 


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
